# table with fixed header and hotizontal-vertical scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm want to build a scrollable (both directions) table with fixed header, no luck so far.

I tried the followings:

a, solution:

```
<div style='overflow: auto;'>
  <table>...</table>
</div>
```

problem: the header not fixed.

b, solution:

```
<div style='overflow-x: auto;'>
  <table>(header only)</table>
  <div style='overflow-y: auto;'>
    <table>(data only)</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

problem: the vertical scrollbar visible only when the horizontal scrollbar is at rightmost position.

There must be some easy way to do this, but the lack of my HTML, CSS knowledge prevents me to solve this problem alone. I did look around here, haven't found similar problem yet.

**(this is not the actual code, just this way easier to explain the situation.)**

**update: corrected the code to make the "write-only" users happy**

Comment: `<div overflow: auto>`??? learn HTML,CSS basics first

Comment: goto [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) and learn css basics........... the code should be like __<div style="overflow-x: auto">__

Comment: try: `<div style="overflow: auto;">` ;)

Comment: you should have read my post fully: "(this is not the actual code, just this way easier to explain the situation.)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

```
<style>
  div {position: absolute;}
  td {width: 250px;}
</style>

<div id='div_base' style='left: 20px; top: 20px; width: 600px; height: 90px; border: 1px black solid;'>
  <div id='div_header' style='height: 25px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;'>
    <table id='table_header' style='position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1500px;'>
      <tr style='background-color: grey; color: white;'>
        <td>name</td><td>phone</td><td>e-mail</td><td>date</td><td>company</td><td>city</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id='div_data' style='top: 25px; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; overflow: auto;'>
    <table id='table_data' style='left: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 1500px;'>
      <tr style='background-color: white;'>
        <td>John Smith</td><td>11111111</td><td>johnsmith@common.com</td><td>2010-10-10 10:10:10</td><td>World Rule ltd.</td><td>London</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='background-color: silver;'>
        <td>Jane Smith</td><td>22222222</td><td>janesmith@common.com</td><td>2011-11-11 11:11:11</td><td>Power Gmbh.</td><td>Paris</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='background-color: white;'>
        <td>John Doe</td><td>33333333</td><td>johnsmith@missing.com</td><td>2012-12-12 12:12:12</td><td>ACME</td><td>New York</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='background-color: silver;'>
        <td>Jane Doe</td><td>44444444</td><td>janesmith@missing.com</td><td>2013-13-13 13:13:13</td><td>Evil Corp.</td><td>Budapest</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function doScrollEvent(ev) {
    var table = document.getElementById('table_header');
    table.style.left = -ev.target.scrollLeft + 'px';
  } 

  var container = document.getElementById('div_data');
  if(container.addEventListener)
    container.addEventListener('scroll', doScrollEvent, false);   
  else if (container.attachEvent)
    container.attachEvent('onscroll', doScrollEvent); 
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for this one, i was exactly looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

To make the header fixed you would use style in the header dive like this:

```
<div style="position: fixed;">
    /*Header Text*/
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div style="position: absolute;">
    /*Header Text*/
</div>
```

To make the box scrollable both ways you inside to div you would add:

```
<div style="overflow: scroll;"></div>
```

Comment: i want the header scroll horizontally along with the data

Comment: "position: fixed;" should do that.

Comment: could you provide the full code please? I tried your suggestion, but I haven't got the desired behavior, probably I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
<div class="outer-container"> <!-- absolute positioned container -->
<div class="inner-container">

    <div class="table-header">
        <table id="headertable" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="header-cell col1">One</th>
                    <th class="header-cell col2">Two</th>
                    <th class="header-cell col3">Three</th>
                    <th class="header-cell col4">Four</th>
                    <th class="header-cell col5">Five</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="table-body">
        <table id="bodytable" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                    <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

CSS::

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse; /* make simple 1px lines borders if border defined */
}
tr {
    width: 100%;
}

.outer-container {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 300px;
    bottom:40px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.inner-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
.table-header {
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
}
.table-body {
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width: inherit;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.header-cell {
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: left;
    height: 40px;
}
.body-cell {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: left;
}
.col1, .col3, .col4, .col5 {
    width:120px;
    min-width: 120px;
}
.col2 {
    min-width: 300px;
}
```